# Django prefetch related of prefetched related

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a few models that are in the fashion of parent - child - child of child. In my views.py I did 
`swsallsteps = sws_dcoument_step.objects.filter().prefetch_related(my various models)`

The issue I'm having is how can I prefetch the related information from the related information? I'm getting lost in this portion. Example I have this in my views.py

```
  swsallsteps = SWS_Document_Step.objects\
      .filter(document_number=document_id)\
      .prefetch_related('swes_step_set', 'sws_step_hazard_set', 'sws_step_ppe_set')
```

This is returning exactly what I'd expect. The SWES_Step_Set associated to SWS_Document_Step like my first 2 models below. How though, can I pull the SWES_Step_Picture model associated to SWES_Document_Step? I imagine it's much more simple than I'm making it.

Models for example below.

```
class SWS_Document_Step(models.Model):

    STEP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('People', 'People'),
        ('Quality', 'Quality'),
        ('Velocity', 'Velocity'),
        ('Cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    document_number = models.ForeignKey(SWS_Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sws_sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=True, null=True)
    sws_work_element_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sws_step_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STEP_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWS Document Step'
        verbose_name_plural = '005 SWS Document Steps'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.document_number) + " " + str(self.sws_sequence_number) + " " + str(self.sws_work_element_description)

class SWES_Step(models.Model):

    STEP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('People', 'People'),
        ('Quality', 'Quality'),
        ('Velocity', 'Velocity'),
        ('Cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    sws_document_id = models.ForeignKey(SWS_Document_Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    swes_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    swes_step_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=STEP_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWES Step'
        verbose_name_plural = '012 SWES Document Steps'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sws_document_id) + " " + str(self.swes_description)

class SWES_Step_Picture(models.Model):

    swes_step = models.ForeignKey(SWES_Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sws_step_photo = models.ImageField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWES Step Picture'
        verbose_name_plural = '015 SWES Step Pictures'
```

Comment: I think that something like `swsallsteps = SWS_Document_Step.objects\
      .filter(document_number=document_id)\
      .prefetch_related('swes_step_set', 'sws_step_hazard_set', 'sws_step_ppe_set', 'swes_step_set__pictures')` should work if you set the `related_name=pictures` on `SWES_Step_Picture.swes_step`

Comment: @MarkR. How would I go about pulling that into my HTML templates, or at the very least test to make sure I get what I'm expecting?

Comment: @Timothyjames67 how you pull that into a template is not really related, `prefetch_related` only ensures more optimal database access (1 extra query per prefetch queryset). You can just loop through your `SWS_Document_Step` objects, for each of them loop through the `swes_step_set` and for each of those loop through the `pictures`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from django_single.models import *
>>> SWSDocumentStep.objects.select_related('document_number').prefetch_related('swesstep_set', 'swesstep_set__swessteppicture_set')
DEBUG (0.004) SELECT "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."id", "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."document_number_id", "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."sws_sequence_number", "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."sws_work_element_description", "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."sws_step_type", "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."pub_date", "django_single_swsdocument"."id", "django_single_swsdocument"."name" FROM "django_single_swsdocumentstep" INNER JOIN "django_single_swsdocument" ON ("django_single_swsdocumentstep"."document_number_id" = "django_single_swsdocument"."id") WHERE "django_single_swsdocumentstep"."id" = 10  LIMIT 21; args=(10,)
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "django_single_swesstep"."id", "django_single_swesstep"."sws_document_id", "django_single_swesstep"."swes_description", "django_single_swesstep"."swes_step_type", "django_single_swesstep"."pub_date" FROM "django_single_swesstep" WHERE "django_single_swesstep"."sws_document_id" IN (10); args=(10,)
DEBUG (0.002) SELECT "django_single_swessteppicture"."id", "django_single_swessteppicture"."swes_step_id", "django_single_swessteppicture"."pub_date" FROM "django_single_swessteppicture" WHERE "django_single_swessteppicture"."swes_step_id" IN (10); args=(10,)
<QuerySet [<SWSDocumentStep: SWSDocument object (10) None >]>
```

Sorry, couldn't help but rename your models, they're examples of what not to do:

1.[Don't](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) use `ForeignKey` and add `_id` to the end of the model, example: `sws_document_id` > `sws_document`

2.In python we don't add `_` between our words in a class, example: `SWES_Step_Picture` > `SWESStepPicture`

```
# to get this to work you will need to do the following steps
mkdir django_simple/migrations
touch django_simple/django_simple.py
# copy and paste the content of the file bellow in django_simple/django_simple.py
python django_simple/django_simple.py makemigrations
python django_simple/django_simple.py migrate
python django_simple/django_simple.py shell -c 'from django_simple.models import *; SWESStepPicture.objects.create(swes_step=SWESStep.objects.create(sws_document=SWSDocumentStep.objects.create(document_number=SWSDocument.objects.create(name="blah"))))'
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

# Stolen from: https://mlvin.xyz/django-single-file-project.html

import inspect
from types import ModuleType
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

# the current folder name will also be our app
APP_LABEL = os.path.basename(BASE_DIR)


settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
    MIDDLEWARE=[],
    INSTALLED_APPS=[
        APP_LABEL,
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    ],
    DATABASES={
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    },
    LOGGING={
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'simple': {
                'format': "%(levelname)s %(message)s",
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'simple',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.db.backends': {'handlers': ['console'], 'level': 'DEBUG', 'propagate': False},
            'django.db.backends.schema': {'level': 'ERROR'},  # Causes sql logs to duplicate -- really annoying
        }
    }
)


import django
django.setup()

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class SWSDocument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWS Document'
        verbose_name_plural = '001 SWS Document'
        app_label = APP_LABEL


class SWSDocumentStep(models.Model):

    STEP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('People', 'People'),
        ('Quality', 'Quality'),
        ('Velocity', 'Velocity'),
        ('Cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    document_number = models.ForeignKey(SWSDocument, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sws_sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=True, null=True)
    sws_work_element_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sws_step_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STEP_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWS Document Step'
        verbose_name_plural = '005 SWS Document Steps'
        app_label = APP_LABEL

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.document_number) + " " + str(self.sws_sequence_number) + " " + str(self.sws_work_element_description)


class SWESStep(models.Model):

    STEP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('People', 'People'),
        ('Quality', 'Quality'),
        ('Velocity', 'Velocity'),
        ('Cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    sws_document = models.ForeignKey(SWSDocumentStep, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    swes_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    swes_step_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=STEP_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWES Step'
        verbose_name_plural = '012 SWES Document Steps'
        app_label = APP_LABEL

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sws_document_id) + " " + str(self.swes_description)


class SWESStepPicture(models.Model):

    swes_step = models.ForeignKey(SWESStep, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # sws_step_photo = models.ImageField()  # too lazy to install pillow
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWES Step Picture'
        verbose_name_plural = '015 SWES Step Pictures'
        app_label = APP_LABEL


# Can't use `dumpdata` without it -- this will set it for ALL apps, the app_config is shared
SWESStepPicture._meta.app_config.models_module = '__main__'

# Used so you can do 'from <name of file>.models import *'
models_module = ModuleType(APP_LABEL + '.models')
for variable_name, value in list(locals().items()):
    # We are only interested in models
    if inspect.isclass(value) and issubclass(value, models.Model):
        setattr(models_module, variable_name, value)
sys.modules[models_module.__name__] = models_module

urlpatterns = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
else:
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    get_wsgi_application()
```